# i can't invoke with an argument list of type string?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

```
var query = PFQuery(className: "University")
    query.whereKey("classEnrolledName", equalTo:"fml")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil {
            // The find succeeded.
            NSLog("Successfully retrieved \(objects!.count) scores.")

            // Do something with the found objects
            if let objects = objects {
               for object in objects {
                  NSLog("%@", object.objectId)
                  self.funlists.append(object.objectId)
               }
            }
            } else {
            // Log details of the failure
            NSLog("Error: %@ %@", error!, error!.userInfo!)
        }
    }
```

getting an error on both lines

`NSLog("%@", object.objectId)`

and

```
self.funlists.append(object.objectId)
```

saying  i can't invoke with an argument list of type string?!

Comment: Did you just re edit you post for a completely different question? Don't do that otherwise the answers bellow will make no sense and people will be frustrate trying to understand what is going on. If your first question was resolved just flag as resolved and create a new one for your new problem, so when people is search for the same problem they can easily find it. Thanks

Comment: About your new question in swift you should use println instead NSLog, try to use println("The value of  object.objectId is \( object.objectId)") that should solve your problem

Comment: Great! You welcome, just remember to flag the question as answered so other people don't try to answer and few free to post as many new questions as you need instead edit old one :) Good Luck!

Comment: @IcaroNZ, thanks i'll definitely keep that in mind! One more error if i can pick at your brain for another moment, I'm getting the error, "cannot invoke 'dequeReusable...' with an argument of type '(String)'" in this method   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath:   NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        var cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as UITableViewCell
        
        cell.textLabel!.text = self.funlists[indexPath.row]
        
        return cell
    } (where i initialize cell), any advice?

Comment: Do you have a cell with identifier "cell"? If so is it of type UITableViewCell?

Comment: @IcaroNZ, sorry i'm extremely new to Xcode and swift. When you mean an identifier "cell" are you referring too in the story board when i click my UITableView? It does say that the identifier is named cell, but i'm not sure how to confirm the type UITableViewCell

Comment: Yes this one, you change the cell class in the same why you change the viewController class

Comment: @IcarNZ, unfortunately it is of type UITableViewCell. i greatly appreciate your help though!!!!

Comment: Just open a new question maybe someone else will be able to help you, sorry I am not seem what else could be wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`objects:[AnyObject]?` is optional. You need to unwrap it. [More info on optionals](http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/swift-optionals-use-let/)

```
if let objects = objects {
    for object in objects {
        NSLog("%@", object.objectId)
            self.funlists.append(object.objectId)
    }
}
```

Comment: after doing this i now have an error at both         NSLog("%@", object.objectId)
and             self.funlists.append(object.objectId)
saying i can't invoke with an argument list of type string?! any advice?

Comment: Make sure your variable type is matching with the type of whatever you're returning from your `object`. Is `funlists` array of strings? If so, you can do `self.funlists.append("\(object.objectId)")`

Comment: thanks that god rid of the error on that line, any advice on the line above it, it has the same error         NSLog("%@", object.objectId)

Comment: NSLog("%@", "\(object.objectId)")
 seems to have gotten rid of the error

Comment: Cool. Please mark the question as answered so that other community members will benefit it from as well.